# Django Linkedin API Search listings by job title

Tags: python, django, api, linkedin-api, listings

Im trying to write a small django app that basically provides a search field that allows a user to enter a job description and then return a set of results that match that criteria. Ive tried googling the problem to no avail. Is this possible? And if so, are there any tutorials you could point me to.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more cpecific. Should it be world wide search? What industry? And also where is the diff between your app and Google.